# How to apply a css property after an animation finishes in another class?

Tags: css, sass

With this code:

```
 .expanded {
  max-height: 1000px;
  overflow: visible;

  .ui-collapse-header-button-container {
    .ui-fab i {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like the div with the `.expanded` class to have the property `overflow: visible` once the icon animation finishes. Is there a way to do it using only css/sass? (no javascript!).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may use animation timing on both elements if there is no user event

Comment: I agree that's the best CSS-only solution - run two simultaneous animations: one on the icon and one on `.expanded`. The property `overflow` isn't animatable as such but you can still change its value from `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: visible` using a `transition` or a `@keyframes animation`.